# Creating Stored procedures in HSQLDB

Tags: stored-procedures, hsqldb

I have created a table in HSQLDB with the below structure

```
CREATE TABLE salary (
    emp_no INT NOT NULL,
    salary_amount INT NOT NULL,
    bonus INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)
);
```

and stored procedure below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_bonus_by_emp_no(IN EMP_KEY integer, IN ADDL_BONUS integer)
BEGIN 
    UPDATE salary
    SET bonus = ADDL_BONUS + bonus
    WHERE emp_no=EMP_KEY;
```

Getting error when i run this command, getting error

> unexcepted token UPDATE required:ATOMIC : line:2/Error code-5581/42581

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The message means you must use BEGIN ATOMIC. See the examples in the Guide for the other additions you need to make:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_psm_vars